# Diagnosing Akka--number of active and available threads?

Tags: scala, akka

In my application, I sometimes get into a state where work isn't getting done by my workers, but the CPU and disk are basically sitting idle. I'd like to be able to regular log (e.g. to statsd or similar) the number of active worker threads and maximum number of active worker threads for each scheduler. Then if we have problems, we can check the logs and cross-reference to determine if the problems coincided with our thread pools being totally full.

I can't seem to find any methods to determine, at the current moment in time, the total thread pool size and number of running threads in each pool. Where should I look?

Comment: Your actors may be doing some blocking operations, I'd suggest you to use some simple tool like `jstack` to determine what the threads are waiting for.

Comment: Have you tried the Typesafe Console? I used it once and it gave me all the sort of information that you can find useful about how many actor are there, what are they doing and so on. Check it out at http://typesafe.com/platform/runtime/console